# Alternativa3D - Outlining 3D objects

Tags: flash, shader, 3d-engine, molehill

I'm trying to make black-outlined objects using the Alternativa3D engine, I'm going for a cartoonish look. How can I do this?

Comment: Hehe, [Borderlands](http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/videogames/detail-page/borderlands.02.lg.jpg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a brief look through the Alternativa3D documentation and couldn't find materials or shaders for that. Would you be able to use an alternative 3D API, like [Away3D](http://away3d.com/) ?
If so, Away3D already offers a CellShaded material, as you can see in [this sample](http://not-so-stupid.com/clients/not-so-stupid/away4/duck/):

[image: Away3D Cell Shading Example]

Also, you have the [source](https://github.com/away3d/away3d-examples-broomstick/blob/master/src/CelShadingTest.as) for the above example:

```
var material : ColorMaterial = new ColorMaterial(0xfbcbc1);
material.ambientColor = 0xdd5525;
material.ambient = 1; //0xdd5525;
material.specular = .25;
material.diffuseMethod = new CelDiffuseMethod(3);
material.specularMethod = new CelSpecularMethod();
material.addMethod(new OutlineMethod(0x000000, 2/50));
CelSpecularMethod(material.specularMethod).smoothness = .01;
CelDiffuseMethod(material.diffuseMethod).smoothness = .01;
material.lights = [ _light, _light2, _light3 ];
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if A3D has a built-in solution, but in general case you should make the second model, place it under the existing one and apply entrude and tint to black shaders to it.

Comment: I think that's a terrible idea. Double your poly count just to get an outline? Surely this is something a shader could handle or some other form of post processing.